# Glide with Setter method url image source

Tags: android-glide

I would like to set the value of an image attribute in an object class as you would below but using Glide

```
try {
InputStream stream = new URL("my url").openStream();
Bitmap pictureBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
"my model class".setImageBitmap(pictureBitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
```

I guess this is how you fetch the image from the url source using Glide as Bitmap

```
Glide
     .with(getContext())
     .load("my url")
     .asBitmap()....
```

Comment: so, what is exactly your question?

Comment: @ikhsan complete the code with Glide to set the  image attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SimpleTarget** as a parameter on ***into*** method. It will load your bitmap and you can put it into your image model after image ready.

```
 Glide
.with(getApplicationContext())
.load(IMAGE_URL)
.asBitmap()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
    @Override
    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
        YourModelClass.setImageBitmap(resource);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ikhsan

Comment: @Geob please accept the answer if it fix your issue.